Computation on right action of Lie algebra on characters of its Lie group
Question:
I'm reading this essay about the representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. In the proof of Proposition 10.6, it is proven that
$$[R_{x_+}\varepsilon^m_s](1)=s+1+m$$
and I have a question about this computation. Here,
$$x_+=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\-i&-1\end{bmatrix}\qquad \varepsilon^m_s(g)=\chi_ssgn^n\delta^{1/2}(p)\varepsilon^m(k),$$
where $g=pk$ ($p$ is a upper triangular matrix and $k$ is a rotation matrix) and for an upper triangular matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}t&x\\0&1/t\end{bmatrix}$, $\chi_ssgn^n(A)=|t|^ssgn^n(t)$ and $\delta(A)=t^2$ and finally for a rotational matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(t)&-\sin(t)\\\sin(t)&\cos(t)\end{bmatrix}$, $\varepsilon^m(B)=e^{imt}$.
Answer:
In the proof, it is given a $2x_+=h-\kappa i-2i\nu_+$, where
$$h=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\quad \kappa=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\quad \nu_+=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Following this decomposition, I computed that
$$[R_{h/2}\varepsilon_s^m](1)=\frac{1}{2}[R_h\varepsilon_s^m](1)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon^m_s(exp(th))=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon^m_s(\begin{bmatrix}e^t&0\\0&e^{-t}\end{bmatrix})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}e^{ts}e^{ts}=s$$
In the similar manner,
$$[R_{-\kappa i/2}\varepsilon_s^m](1)=\frac{-i}{2}[R_\kappa\varepsilon_s^m](1)=\frac{-i}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon^m_s(exp(t\kappa))=\frac{-i}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon^m_s(exp(\begin{bmatrix}0&-t\\t&0\end{bmatrix}))$$
$$=\frac{-i}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon_s^m(\begin{bmatrix}\cos(t)&-\sin(t)\\\sin(t)&\cos(t)\end{bmatrix})=\frac{-i}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}e^{imt}=\frac{m}{2}$$
and that
$$[R_{-i\nu_+}\varepsilon_s^m](1)=-i[R_{\nu_+}\varepsilon_s^m](1)=-i\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon_s^m(exp(t\nu_+))=-i\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon_s^m(I+t\nu_+)=-i\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\varepsilon_s^m(\begin{bmatrix}1&t\\0&1\end{bmatrix})=-i\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}1=0.$$
So what I obtained is just $s+m/2$. Where do I get wrong? Any helps or hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...
